# better way to push json into different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

i want to push my json into different array.

Before I use if function inside my for loop it works fine, but i like to know if there is a simpler method, since if i have a lot of array I will have lots of if function inside my loop.

part of my json

```
[{"FROM_CURRENCY":"TWD","TO_CURRENCY":"AUD","CONVERSION_RATE":".0359"}
,{"FROM_CURRENCY":"HKD","TO_CURRENCY":"AUD","CONVERSION_RATE":".1393"}
,{"FROM_CURRENCY":"USD","TO_CURRENCY":"CNY","CONVERSION_RATE":"6.2448"}
,{"FROM_CURRENCY":"TWD","TO_CURRENCY":"CNY","CONVERSION_RATE":".2073"}
,{"FROM_CURRENCY":"EUR","TO_CURRENCY":"JPY","CONVERSION_RATE":"139.2115"}
,{"FROM_CURRENCY":"CNY","TO_CURRENCY":"TWD","CONVERSION_RATE":"4.8229"},
```

right now what i have inside my loop

```
if(json[i].TO_CURRENCY == 'TWD'){
        arrayApp.TWD.push(json[i]);}

if(json[i].TO_CURRENCY == 'HKD'){
        arrayApp.HKD.push(json[i]);}
```

because i have many different currency i have to write a alot

here is what i'm thinking but doesn't seem to work

```
var setArrayCurr='';
for ( i in json ) { 
    setArrayCurr=json[i].TO_CURRENCY

    arrayApp.setArrayCurr.push(json[i]);

} //end of loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var arrayApp = {};
for (i in json) {
    var arrayKey = json[i].TO_CURRENCY

    var array = arrayApp[arrayKey];
    //if first time for the key, then create an empty erray for the key.
    if (!array) {
        array = arrayApp[arrayKey] = [];
    }

    array.push(json[i]);

} //end of loop
```

end result would be multiple arrays grouped by the currency:

```
{
    "AWD": [ /* all jsons with currency 'AWD' */ ],
    "TWD": [ /* all jsons with currency 'TWD' */ ],
    "HKD": [ /* all jsons with currency 'HKD' */ ]
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because you have set your setArrayCurr to string not array.

which means every time you declare setArrayCurr, it will change its context but not add nor categorize it.

```
var setArrayCurr = [];
for(var i in json){
 setArrayCurr[json[i].TO_CURRENCY] =json[i];
}
```

this should put your json datas to each section in setArrayCurr array.